# how to redirect to struts action from java script in struts 2?

Tags: javascript, struts2

how to redirect to struts action from java script?

if condition in the script got success then i need to invoke one action in the config xml, otherwise no action invoking the control needs to stay at same page? please help on this?

Java Script

```
    function displayDate()
{

       var x=document.getElementsByName("userName")
    if(x = "shan")
    {   
    alert("shankarasd");
    document.myForm.action ="/setUpForInsertOrUpdate";
    document.myForm.submit();
    }

}
```

HTML

```
    <html>
        <body>
        <s:form action="HelloWorld" >
            <s:textfield name="userName" label="User Name" />
            <s:submit onclick="displayDate()" />
        </s:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

config.xml

```
 <struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="HelloWorld" class="vaannila.HelloWorld.HelloWorld"> 
            <result name="SUCCESS">/success.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="setUpForInsertOrUpdate" method="setUpForInsertOrUpdate" class="vaannila.HelloWorld.HelloWorld">
            <result name="SUCCESS1">/success1.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="back" method="back" class="vaannila.HelloWorld.HelloWorld">
            <result name="SUCCESS2">/success.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: If you want to compare the value of `m` to `1`, you definitely don't want to be using `=` (that's the assignment operator). Instead use `==`.

Comment: it can be any value, i just given an example.

Comment: actually instead of checking m==1, i will get the value from user and used to check there.

Comment: anthony i have updated my qustion,please check this.

Comment: @jcrshankar: whats the issue and i believe `=` is an assignment operator while `==` is comparison

Comment: umesh i need to compare the value only, that' fine. i need help on how to call struts action from java script. plz help on this.

Comment: window.location="setUpForInsertOrUpdate.action"; this line help me to navigate. thanks all.

Answer (score 6):

try it

```
window.location='youractionname'
```

This will redirect your window into your destination

If you want to sent your values to other page, then follow this method

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function displayDate()
{

   var x=document.getElementsByName("userName")
if(x =="shan")
{   
alert("Redirecting");
return true;
}
else{  
alert("Not Redirecting");
return false;
}
}
</script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
  <s:form action="HelloWorld"  onsubmit="displayDate();">
        <s:textfield name="userName" label="User Name" />
        <s:submit onclick="displayDate()" />
    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

What I modified is, changed the function calling from button to form submit.
And removed the unwanted things from function

Comment: i believe OP has already found the solution of the answer as he mentioned in the comment.Still nice solution :)

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi ,It is true that he found code to redirect his page.
But from his question it is clear that he want to sent some form values along with it, which is not possible with the solution he found .
( Logical error) :-)

Comment: Actually after answering only I saw his comment

Answer (score 3):

**you can call action controller with parameter on click event**

```
$('#loginSubmit').click(function(){ 

var Username= take the value for text fields 

var Password =take the value for text fields 
var url = "login"; 

var FormD = '<form method="post" action="' + url + '" id="frmSubmit" autocomplete="off">';

 FormD += '<input type="hidden" name="Username" value="' + Username+ '" />'; 

FormD += '<input type="hidden" name="Password" value="'  + Password+ '" />'; 

FormD += '</form>';
 $("body").append(FormD); $("#frmSubmit").submit(); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try is:

```
function displayDate(){

    var x=document.getElementsByName("userName")
    if(x = "shan")
    {   
    alert("shankarasd");
    document.myForm.action ="/setUpForInsertOrUpdate";
    document.myForm.submit();


    location.href = "nameaction.action?parameter1="+value1+"&parameter2="+value2;
    }

}
```