# How to call an action in pop up window

Tags: javascript, struts2

I have a JSP where i have a link to open pop-up window(lets say some action in struts xml). In that window, i have 4 dropdowns. Once users select these 4 dropdown and clicked the submit button, an action got called as mentioned in struts xml. ,corresponding mapped pages has to displayed as main and pop up window has to be closed. Any help/idea how to do this? I am new to programming.

Thanks in advance,
Arun

In main.jsp,

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/hello.action" onclick="javascript:void window.open('http://localhost:8080/Strutslearning/hello.action','1379313271736','width=700,height=500,toolbar=0,menubar=1,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0');return false;">Pop-up Window</a>
```

In pop-up jsp

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function checkForm(){
     window.close();
     target="main"
     return true;
 }

 </script>


<body>
<form action="selectAction.action" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)">
<s:select name="mylist" list="%{mylist}"></s:select>
<s:submit ></s:submit>

</form>
```

Comment: All i need is, "Output page has to be displayed as main page in browser"

Comment: This will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432092/how-to-redirect-to-struts-action-from-java-script-in-struts-2

Answer (score 0):

Add `target="_parent"` to your form:

```
<form action="selectAction.action" 
      onsubmit="javascript:window.close();" 
      target="_parent">
```

Note that in your `<a>` element you don't need to reference the Action twice: use `href` + `target="_blank"`, or `href="#"` + `onclick="window.open(...)"`, not both.